# AngularJS custom directive not working properly

Tags: asp.net-web-api, angularjs-directive

I have created a custom directive which I thought of using throughout my application to display ModelState errors (thrown from MVC web api) but the errors are not shown in the html piece generated by the custom directive but error div is displayed without any messages. Please help me.

```
cmApp.directive("modelError", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
           errors: '@'
        },
        template: '<div class="row">' +
                    '<br />' +
                    '<div class="span10">' +
                        '<div class="alert-error alert" ng-show="errors" ng-switch="errors.length">' +
                          '<strong>Error!</strong>' +                              
                          '<ul ng-switch-default>' +
                            '<li ng-repeat="error in errors">{{error}}</li>' +
                          '</ul>' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>',
    };
});
```

Html code:

```
<model-error errors="{{modelErrors}}"></model-error>
```

Controller code:

```
$scope.modelErrors = validationService.getModelErrors(response);
```

I am only seeing the "Error!" div but not the error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to interpolate before passing in the attribute value:

```
<model-error errors="modelErrors"></model-error>
```

Also, try changing the isolated scope type to `=`:

```
scope: {
       errors: '='
},
```

From the stable [directive docs](http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.8/docs/guide/directive):

> scope - If set to:
>
> true - then a new scope will be created for this directive. If
>   multiple directives on the same element request a new scope, only one
>   new scope is created. The new scope rule does not apply for the root
>   of the template since the root of the template always gets a new
>   scope.
>
> {} (object hash) - then a new 'isolate' scope is created. The
>   'isolate' scope differs from normal scope in that it does not
>   prototypically inherit from the parent scope. This is useful when
>   creating reusable components, which should not accidentally read or
>   modify data in the parent scope.  The 'isolate' scope takes an object
>   hash which defines a set of local scope properties derived from the
>   parent scope. These local properties are useful for aliasing values
>   for templates. Locals definition is a hash of local scope property to
>   its source:
>
> @ or @attr - bind a local scope property to the value of DOM
>   attribute. The result is always a string since DOM attributes are
>   strings. If no attr name is specified then the attribute name is
>   assumed to be the same as the local name. Given  and widget definition of scope: { localName:'@myAttr' },
>   then widget scope property localName will reflect the interpolated
>   value of hello {{name}}. As the name attribute changes so will the
>   localName property on the widget scope. The name is read from the
>   parent scope (not component scope).
>
> = or =attr - set up bi-directional binding between a local scope property and the parent scope property of name defined via the value
>   of the attr attribute. If no attr name is specified then the attribute
>   name is assumed to be the same as the local name. Given  and widget definition of scope: {
>   localModel:'=myAttr' }, then widget scope property localModel will
>   reflect the value of parentModel on the parent scope. Any changes to
>   parentModel will be reflected in localModel and any changes in
>   localModel will reflect in parentModel.
>
> & or &attr - provides a way to execute an expression in the context of
>   the parent scope. If no attr name is specified then the attribute name
>   is assumed to be the same as the local name. Given  and widget definition of scope: {
>   localFn:'&myAttr' }, then isolate scope property localFn will point to
>   a function wrapper for the count = count + value expression. Often
>   it's desirable to pass data from the isolated scope via an expression
>   and to the parent scope, this can be done by passing a map of local
>   variable names and values into the expression wrapper fn. For example,
>   if the expression is increment(amount) then we can specify the amount
>   value by calling the localFn as localFn({amount: 22}).